# How to detect if the data was performed log2() transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, discrete-mathematics

I would like to know:

How to detect if the data was performed log2() transformation?

For example,

> data <- c(12, 23, 10, 6, 2, 8)
>
> data
>
> [1] 12 23 10  6  2  8
>
> log2Data <- log2(data)
>
> log2Data
>
> [1] 3.584963 4.523562 3.321928 2.584963 1.000000 3.000000

Given the **log2Data**, how can I know if it is in the log2 space?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you know about the process that generates the numbers?

Comment: that is just what I ask. Basically, I just know the given data such as: 3.584963 4.523562 3.321928 2.584963 1.000000 3.000000 **or** 12 23 10 6 2 8. How can I know if the given data is located in Log space.